# How exactly does registering and selecting a socket work?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm learning some networking with Python. While I find a lot of code samples, I don't find any explanations for some pieces of code. In the selectors module there seem to be two important functions, register and select. I can't find a good explanation on what exactly they do so I was hoping someone here could help.

As an example I played around a bit with some sample code from the python documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html. This code sample ends with

```
sel.register(sock, selectors.EVENT_READ, accept)

while True:
events = sel.select()
for key, mask in events:
    callback = key.data
    callback(key.fileobj, mask)
```

where "accept" is a function defined elsewhere in the code and "sel" is a selector. I've noticed that at first the select() call blocks the code until a connection is made by a client. But what exactly does it return? From some experiments it seems to return a list with an item for each registered socket that got updated. But what is the "mask" variable? In the python documentation it says that it is *"a bitmask of events ready on this file object"*, but I have no idea what this means and in my experiments it seems to be just the value 1.

Also, when I replace the for-loop by "print(events)", I notice that once the socket gets used, the code no longer waits every time at sel.select(). Why is this?

When registering a socket, I don't understand the data argument. The documentation just says it is an *"opaque object"* and it's *None* by default. Here it seems to be the function that should be called when a socket is used, but is this always the case? And just to be clear, the selectors.EVENT_READ argument indicates that the socket can only receive information, not send it, right?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

> I've noticed that at first the select() call blocks the code until a connection is made by a client.

More accurately, it blocks until one or more of the registered sockets matches one of its registered events.  So, in your example, `select()` will block indefinitely (since you are not specifying a value for the `timeout` parameter) until `sock` reports the `EVENT_READ` event is ready.

> But what exactly does it return? From some experiments it seems to return a list with an item for each registered socket that got updated. But what is the "mask" variable?

This is answered in the same document you linked to:

> This returns **a list of `(key, events)` tuples**, one for each ready file object.
>
> `key` is the [SelectorKey](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html#selectors.SelectorKey) instance corresponding to a ready file object. **`events` is a bitmask of events ready on this file object.**

> In the python documentation it says that it is "a bitmask of events ready on this file object", but I have no idea what this means

You can register multiple events for a socket.  The reported `mask` will tell you which of those events is actually ready.

> and in my experiments it seems to be just the value 1.

That is the numeric value for `EVENT_READ`.  That is the only value you are getting, because that is the only event you are registering.  But there are other events you can register, such as `EVENT_WRITE`.

> Also, when I replace the for-loop by "print(events)", I notice that once the socket gets used, the code no longer waits every time at sel.select(). Why is this?

Because you are not calling your `accept()` function anymore to read data from the socket.  The socket will remain in a readable state as long as it has pending data waiting to be read.  Thus your `select()` will continue to report that `EVENT_READ` is ready for the socket until all of its pending data has been read.

> When registering a socket, I don't understand the data argument.

It is whatever you want it to be.  You can associate whatever custom data you want with your event registrations, and then `select()` will give that data back to you each time an event is reported.

> The documentation just says it is an "opaque object" and it's None by default. Here it seems to be the function that should be called when a socket is used, but is this always the case?

No.  It can be whatever you need it to be.

> And just to be clear, the selectors.EVENT_READ argument indicates that the socket can only receive information, not send it, right?

No.  It means that you are interested in being notified only when the socket is in a readable state.  You can always write to a socket, at least until `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` or `close()` is called on it.  For a non-blocking socket, `send()` can fail if it would block (because the receiver's buffer is full), in which case you would have to wait for `EVENT_WRITE` to be ready on the socket (the receiver is ready to receive more data) before you can send data on that socket again.